# How to pass a macro-argument to an expression within the same macro?

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming, default-constructor

```
macro myMacro(name,arg)
    :(struct $name
       $(esc(arg.args[1]))
       function $name(;$(esc(arg.args[1]))=arg.args[2].args[2])
         new($(esc(arg.args[1])))
       end
    end)
end
```

I'm trying to create a struct with a default value that spouses to be the second argument from the macro. I know when I define `arg.args[2].args[2]` as default argument it will give an error, cause `arg.args[2].args[2]` is not defined inside the `struct` but I have no idea how to define it.

The macro should expand to:

```
macroexpand(Main,:(@myMacro myM ((arg,(default=10)))))


:(struct myM
      arg
      function myM(; arg = 10)
          new(arg)
      end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, just a couple of issues:

1. The `esc` isn't necessary here. Usually, to avoid conflicts with variables in the macro calls' scopes, variables local to the macro's returned expression are renamed by `gensym`, and global variables are taken from the macro *definition*'s scope. `esc` undos this for an expression, so variables in that expression could mix with the macro call scope. In your case, the variables you tried to `esc` are local to a `struct` and a `function`, no chance of mixing with the macro call scope anyway.
2. You forgot to interpolate the `arg.args[2].args[2]` bit.

```
macro myMacro(name,arg)
    :(struct $name
       $(arg.args[1])
       function $name(; $(arg.args[1]) = $(arg.args[2].args[2]) )
         new( $(arg.args[1]) )
       end
    end)
end
```